# I need an sql query to give me the result from the both tables as appeared in the image uploaded

Tags: sql-server, join

[image: This image is the result given. The first two are correct but the result query is what I need.]
First sql table

```
select distinct 
    d.fleet_no as [FLEET],  
    a.[LAST DEPARTURE], 
    a.[OFF DAYS] 
FROM tim d INNER JOIN 
(   SELECT 
        fleet_no,  
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),cast(max(tDepart) as date), 107) AS [LAST DEPARTURE],  
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), datediff(d,max(tDepart),Getdate())) AS [OFF DAYS] 
    FROM tim 
    GROUP BY fleet_no
)   a ON a.fleet_no = d.fleet_no
```

Second sql Table is

```
SELECT distinct 
    d.fleet_no as [FLEET],
    a.[LAST DEPARTURE],
    a.[OFF DAYS] 
FROM exprtim d  INNER JOIN 
(   SELECT  fleet_no,  
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), cast(max(tDepart) as date), 107) AS [LAST DEPARTURE],  
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), datediff(d,max(tDepart),Getdate())) AS [OFF DAYS] 
    FROM exprtim 
    GROUP BY fleet_no 
)   a ON a.fleet_no = d.fleet_no
```

What query would give me the result in the image. The Fisrt and Second set query are given above.

Comment: I think the problem arises trying to compare dates *formatted as text* rather than as DATETIME values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without digging too deeply into any logic issues, let me at least propose a way to simplify the query with some [Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
;with 
FirstInnerSet AS
(   SELECT 
        fleet_no,  
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),cast(max(tDepart) as date), 107) AS [LAST DEPARTURE],  
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), datediff(d,max(tDepart),Getdate())) AS [OFF DAYS] 
    FROM tim 
    GROUP BY fleet_no
),

FirstSet AS
(   select distinct 
        d.fleet_no as [FLEET],  
        a.[LAST DEPARTURE], 
        a.[OFF DAYS] 
    FROM tim d 
    INNER JOIN FirstInnerSet a ON a.fleet_no = d.fleet_no
),

SecondInnerSet AS
(   SELECT 
        fleet_no,  
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),cast(max(tDepart) as date), 107) AS [LAST DEPARTURE],  
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), datediff(d,max(tDepart),Getdate())) AS [OFF DAYS] 
    FROM exprtim  
    GROUP BY fleet_no
),

SecondSet AS
(   SELECT distinct 
        d.fleet_no as [FLEET],
        a.[LAST DEPARTURE],
        a.[OFF DAYS] 
    FROM exprtim d
    INNER JOIN SecondInnerSet a ON a.fleet_no = d.fleet_no
)

select FirstSet.Fleet,
    CASE 
        WHEN firstset.[off days] > secondset.[off days] 
        THEN FirstSet.[Last Departure] 
        ELSE SecondSet.[Last Departure] 
        END AS [LAST DEPARTURE],
    CASE 
        WHEN firstset.[off days] > secondset.[off days] 
        THEN FirstSet.[off days] 
        ELSE SecondSet.[off days] 
        END AS [OFF DAYS]
from FirstSet
inner join SecondSet
    on FirstSet.Fleet = SecondSet.Fleet
    order by FirstSet.Fleet
```

EDIT:

Okay, I've distilled this down considerably by first combining the two datasets you're comparing, THEN calculating the MAX. Try this:

```
;with 
    InnerSet AS
    (   SELECT fleet_no, tDepart FROM tim 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT fleet_no, tDepart FROM exprtim 
    ),

    MainSet AS
    (   SELECT fleet_no, max(tDepart) AS MaxDepart
        FROM InnerSet
        GROUP BY fleet_no
    )

SELECT fleet_no,
    [Last Departure] = MaxDepart,
    [Off Days] = datediff(d,MaxDepart,Getdate())
FROM MainSet
```

Comment: Still the same result. Although I copied your simplicity but no effect in output. This is not the answer

Comment: Find a particular fleet_no giving invalid results, and post the source data and query result in your question.

Comment: I have uploaded an image to the claim, please assist

Comment: I am so sorry not accepting your solution for the last 18 hours. I did not check the Edit below. It worked like Magic. God bless you. Wow... I was even editing the question not knowing you have done everything. Please can you explain your edited code to me?